# How to visualize a Krav Maga straight punch?

Tags: punching, krav-maga

I'm trying to learn the mechanics of a straight punch by myself without an in-person teacher; even youtube videos aren't too clear for me. I'm right handed and want to know exactly how the 45 degree angle happens and how the hand is moved.  Anybody know of a slow-mo super close-up video showing a Krav Maga straight punch? A side view and a front view?  I can't tell how much to rotate my shoulder etc. either as the photos on a site and youtube videos aren't perfectly clear.

Comment: 45 degree angle of what?  The fist?  this video shows a punch finishing with a 90 degree twist (similar to a karate punch) https://youtu.be/v1l-1qfy6X0

Comment: Ya, which angle the punch turns  a close up of how to hit with the two knuckles first while doing the 45 degree twist.

Comment: I don't think you understand the point of angling a punch.  You don't just angle at 45 degrees then twist to 90 degrees for every punch.  That is a specialised karate style punch for hitting the chest and splitting the ribs.  If you look at other krav maga videos they don't do this.  I recommend watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp4q1EuMmoI and other videos by this martial artist.  While I don't believe he trains krav it will show you the correct fist and wrist shape which is the same for any style in any case.

Comment: Geoff Thompson's book "Real punching" is one of the best how-to MA books I've read. Covers boxing, kung fu etc.

Comment: Sure and Geoff explains how to visualize a KM straight punch ... also he could explain chuck norris the roundhouse kick.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are overcomplicating things. 
The Krav-Maga straight punch is called so on purpose, as the boxers punching technique (like a corkscrew) and having a snapping ending is to much technical and needs far more practice to learn.

The straight punch execution:

1. Let your arms hang to the sides naturally.
2. Lift your arms or just your right or left arm to the front.
3. By now you should have a natural hand position by approx. 45° it is not set in stone to be 45° btw.!
4. Close your fist and make sure your big knuckles of the fist are aligned with the big bone of the underarm. You should have a straight line from the underarm to the two knuckles of your fist.
5. When the punch gets executed, twist your shoulder at the same time with your hip and make sure your shoulder passes your center of the body so you generate enough force but don't lose balance and don't lean forward - as this is not intended
6. Recoil your fist after hitting the target.
7. That's basically all to it...

If you Google for Krav-Maga straight punch, you should be able to understand how it works with the information above.

Hope that helps...